# Controls WPF. Очистка полей ввода

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод для очистки текста во всех контролах, он работает только на WinForms, а в WPF нет свойства .Controls. Знаю, что есть метод FindName(), но в этом случае, как я понял, он не подходит, как быть?)

```
private static void CleanAllControlsIn (Control control)
        {
            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) || c.GetType() == typeof (CheckBox) || c.GetType() == typeof (DatePicker))
                    c.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void CleanAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CleanAllControlsIn(this);
        }
```

Comment: Почитайте про визуальные и логические деревья в WPF и методы обхода по ним.

Comment: А лучше используйте привязки, коллекции и прочее

Comment: WPF не снабдили контролы многими методами, потому что в WPF не принято взаимодействовать с контролами напрямую. В WPF используют привязки `Binding`. И работают напрямую с данными, к которым привязаны контролы, а контролы обновляются, когда вы обновляете данные. Можно создать класс со свойствами, привязать к его свойствам группу контролов, и вся очистка сведется к одной строчке кода `MyProperty = new MyClass()`. Profit. Но для самых упорных есть класс [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Если вам интересна тема привязок, то я подробные гайды "как сделать с нуля" давал не один десяток раз здесь на StackOverflow. Сегодня  еще раз я не буду этого делать, в качестве исключения, хотя-бы потому что вы показали 0 строк своего кода из WPF и задали абстрактный вопрос, на который один ответ - "так делать не надо". Но вы можете открыть мой профиль и список ответов в нем, и поискать, большинство ответов - WPF. Уверен, вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос достаточно быстро. Ну и [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview), для начала.